# change the background color of grid.arrange output

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I am using `grid.arrange` from `gridExtra` package to put two graphs on one page and save it to a png file. I like to change the background colour of the final png file that is produced by `grid.arrange`. Is it possible? I was not able to come across any info.

```
grid.arrange(p1, p2, main=textGrob("CPU Util", gp=gpar(cex=1.2, fontface="bold", col="#990000")), ncol = 1, clip=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the `bg =` argument to `png()`

```
library(gridExtra)
library(lattice)

png(bg = "wheat1")
    grid.arrange(xyplot(1:10~1:10, pch=16), xyplot(1:4~1:4, pch=16))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When working with `ggplot2`, I also found useful the `ggdraw()` function from the `cowplot` package as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50011781/5193830).

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Create two plots
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill="wheat1", color = NA))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, drat)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill="wheat1", color = NA))

# stitch them together
g <- grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
# final touch
g2 <- cowplot::ggdraw(g) + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill="wheat1", color = NA))

# check the plot
plot(g2)
# save it as png
ggsave("img/plot-background.png", g2)
```

[image]

While `p1` and `p2` have already the `plot.background` fill set, there remains a thin line between them that disappears when wrapping the `grid.arrange` with `cowplot::ggdraw` using the same fill. As if you stitch two tiles together and then brush over the final layer of paint.

Comment: Thanks. cowplot was a very good solution. I couldn't get the png command working in R Markdown, but cowplot was perfect.