# How to color entire background in ggplot2 when using coord_fixed

Tags: r, ggplot2

When `coord_fixed()` is used with ggplot2, it does not appear to be possible to set the background color of the entire plot. Consider this simple example:

```
library(ggplot2)
test_data <- data.frame(x=1:10)
test_data$y <- sqrt(test_data$x)
p1 <- ggplot(test_data) + geom_point(aes(x, y))
p1
```

[image: Simple example plot]

I can easily make the background another color, such as a garish green color:

```
p1 + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="green"))
```

[image]

But what if I want to use coord_fixed() and color the background green? When I try this `ggplot2` leaves a white strip on the bottom and top of the plot:

```
p1 + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="green")) + coord_fixed()
```

[image]

How do I completely fill the background of the above plot (without the white strips on the top and bottom)? I am producing a number of subplots in a loop to be used with the `animation` package, and I need to ensure the backgrounds of all the subplots are the same (non-white) color, including one on which I need to use `coord_fixed()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
p2 <- p1 + theme(
  plot.background=element_rect(fill="green", color="green")
) + coord_fixed()
grid:::grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill="green", col="green"))
ggplot2:::print.ggplot(p2, newpage=FALSE)
```

First, we set the border and fill to green, then we plot a `grid` rectangle in the same color to fill the viewport, and finally we plot with `ggplot2:::print` setting the `newpage` parameter to false so that it overplots on top of our `grid` rectangle:

[image]

Note that the problem isn't with `ggplot`, but it's just that you are plotting into a viewport that is the wrong size.  If you pre-shape your viewport to the correct aspect ratio, you won't need to worry about setting the viewport contents to green first.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to achieve this effect without relying on non-exported ggplot2 functions, you can also use `ggdraw()` from cowplot:

```
test_data <- data.frame(x=1:10)
test_data$y <- sqrt(test_data$x)
p1 <- ggplot(test_data) + geom_point(aes(x, y))
p2 <- p1 + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="green", color = NA)) + coord_fixed()

# note, don't load cowplot, since it may change your theme
cowplot::ggdraw(p2) + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill="green", color = NA))
```

[image]

The function `ggdraw()` wraps your plot into a new ggplot object that you can then draw onto or style as you wish.

Answer (score 4):

There's a way to do this in `ggplot` by using a secret (undocumented, passed to device in `...`) argument `bg` to `ggsave()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

test_data <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
test_data$y <- sqrt(test_data$x)

p1 <- ggplot(test_data) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "green", color = "green")) +
  coord_fixed()

ggsave("test.png", bg = "green", h = 5)
```

I came here originally because I was using `geom_sf` to plot maps which are by definition fixed to a ratio, and wanted to add a dark background. The `bg` argument also applies to `gganimate::animate()`, if you need to add a background color to a fixed ratio animation.

[image]

Comment: I tried to use ggsave but I had some trouble with plot dimensions. Another alternative is using x11() to create a graphic device for plots and savePlot() for saving them.

Comment: There's no easy way to automate plot dimensions when the ratio is fixed and possibly also unknown. I like to create my own save function where I combine ggsave with `magick::`  `image_read()`, `image_trim()` and `image_write()` to shave off all the whitespace.