# How does one set the background color of a multiplot-figure created via grid.arrange() in an R-shinydashboard?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, gridextra, r-grid

**Description:**

Here is a screenshot of my dashboard that I created with the shiny-package in R. It simply contains a static multiplot (via ggplot and grid.arrange).

[image: Shiny Dashboard with unwanted white areas.]

**Problem:**

There are white areas in the figure which I want to be grey. Just as the background. I have to use grid.arrange to produce the figure.

**Question:**

How do I need to change the code to make the white areas grey? The code is attached below.

```
library(shiny)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bubbles)
require(igraph)
require(rCharts)
library(formattable)
library(networkD3)
library(shinyjs)
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)




ui=dashboardPage(
  #skin = "black",

  dashboardHeader(title =  "MyTitle"),

  dashboardSidebar(
   "nothing here"



  ),


  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
 dashboardBody(

                  plotOutput("meinPiePlot")

                  )
)




server=function(input,output,session){



   output$meinPiePlot=renderPlot({



   Plot01=ggplot(NULL, aes(x="", y=mtcars$qsec, fill=mtcars$disp))+
   geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")+
    coord_polar("y", start=0.8)+
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#ECF0F5",
                               colour = "#ECF0F5",
                                linetype = "solid"),

            strip.background= element_rect(fill = "green",
                                colour = "green",
                                size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),                    


            panel.background=element_rect(fill = "#ECF0F5",
                               colour = "#ECF0F5"),
            #aspect.ratio = 1 / 1.4,
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            legend.position="none"
                                )

       Plot02=ggplot(NULL, aes(x="", y=mtcars$disp, fill=mtcars$mpg))+
   geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")+
    coord_polar("y", start=0.8)+
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#ECF0F5",
                               colour = "#ECF0F5",
                                linetype = "solid"),

            strip.background= element_rect(fill = "green",
                                colour = "green",
                                size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),                    


            panel.background=element_rect(fill = "#ECF0F5",
                               colour = "#ECF0F5"),
            #aspect.ratio = 1 / 1.4,
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            legend.position="none"
                                )

    grid.arrange(Plot01,Plot02, ncol=2)



    })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It would make it much easier to help you if you minimized your example. Many of the packages that you are loading are clearly not necessary (for example).

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `ggdraw()` function from the `cowplot` package as also showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50011781/5193830):

```
g <- grid.arrange(Plot01, Plot02, ncol = 2)
cowplot::ggdraw(g) + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill="#ECF0F5", color = NA))
```

[image]